# Linux drivers for Ricoh Aficio SP 100SU

Tags: drivers, printer

Does anyone have a driver for the Ricoh Aficio SP 100SU on Linux?

Any directions to correctly install it and have the printer work?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: [Look here](https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100.), I use it occasionally, so it's not really tested by me.

Comment: improve your answer by adding more details, don't only refer to a link